# SQL: Update does not affect any row

Tags: sql, db2-400, idbcommand

I want to update a dataset in a DB2/AS400 table.

The problem is if I there is string parameter in the parameters list the command does not find a row to update.

For example: If I run the command only with the company number the command will succeed. If I run the command with the company number and facility number the command fails.

Does anyone have any idea?

```
IDbConnection cn = Tools.GetCnApp();

try
{
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(); 

    sql.AppendLine("UPDATE " + Tools.GetSchemeApp() + "/ChangeReasonAssignments");
    sql.AppendLine("  SET Confirmed = @CONF, Confirmed_By = @CONFBY, Confirmed_At = @CONFAT");
    sql.AppendLine("  WHERE Company = @CONO AND Facility = @FACI AND Department = @DEPT");
    sql.AppendLine("  AND Production_Group = @PRGR AND Manufacturing_Order = @ORDR AND Order_Operation = @OPER");
    sql.AppendLine("  AND Confirmed = 0");

    IDbCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();

    cmd.SetParameter("@CONO", this.CompanyNumber);
    cmd.SetParameter("@FACI", this.FacilityNumber);
    cmd.SetParameter("@DEPT", this.ProductionGroup.Department.Name);
    cmd.SetParameter("@PRGR", this.ProductionGroup.Name);
    cmd.SetParameter("@ORDR", this.ManufacturingNumber);
    cmd.SetParameter("@OPER", this.OperationNumber);
    cmd.SetParameter("@CONFBY", Base.User);
    cmd.SetParameter("@CONFAT", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    cmd.SetParameter("@CONF", 1);

    cmd.CommandText = sql.ToString();

    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
    {
    }
```

#### EDIT

The datatypes in **database** are:

- Company: INTEGER
- Facility: VARCHAR
- Dpartment: VARCHAR
- Production_Group: VARCHAR
- Manufacturing_Order:INTEGER
- Order_Operation: INTEGER

The datatypes in **.NET** are:

- CompanyNumber: int
- FacilityNumber: String
- Departmentname: String
- ProductionGroup: String
- Manufacturingorder: int
- OrderOperation: int

sql.ToString() results:

```
UPDATE TSAEDBDEV/ChangeReasonAssignments SET Confirmed = @CONF, Confirmed_By = @CONFBY, Confirmed_At = @CONFAT WHERE Company = @CONO AND Facility = @FACI AND Confirmed = 0
```

Comment: What type is this.OperationNumber and Order_Operatation?  Is it the same type in the .NET and the database?

Comment: I wonder if this is a padding issue (char[n] vs varchar[n] etc) - what are the SQL types and .NET types?

Comment: Could you share what is returned by sql.ToString() ?

Comment: I know that the naming is sometimes inconsistent but the project grew too fast :)

Comment: The databaas is DB2/AS400. The datatypes in the table and the code ara correct - I checked this very often. 

sql.ToString() will result this:
`
UPDATE TSAEDBDEV/ChangeReasonAssignments
 SET Confirmed = @CONF, Confirmed_By = @CONFBY, Confirmed_At =
 @CONFAT
 WHERE Company = @CONO AND Facility = @FACI
 AND Confirmed = 0
´

Comment: @Gerald: please **don't put** large blocks of text into comments - really really hard to read. Instead: **update** your original question by **editing** it and provide the additional info !!

Comment: The database types are VARCHAR and INTEGER.

Comment: the .NET types are:
Companynumber: int
Facilitynumber: String (I know, why I name it number if its a string...)
Department: String
Productiongroup, Manufacturingnumber and Ordeeroperation are integers

Comment: btw on INSERT and SELECT I use the same parameters and there are no troubles

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the string values into ': `cmd.SetParameter("@DEPT", "'" + this.ProductionGroup.Department.Name + "'");`

Comment: No, this won't be necessary - SQL Server will handle this automatically (if it **is** SQL Server that the OP is using...)